# Check if array contains specific characters and output text string if true using IFS, ISNUMBER, LEFT

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

I am attempting to use an array defined on another sheet using `IFS`, `ISNUMBER` and `LEFT` to output a specific text result if evaluated to TRUE. In theory the formula would check each cell if it matched the first three defined characters and return TRUE so the specified output would return in the single cell. I am also trying to avoid spilling issues so I used `@` to force implicit intersection.

My code:

`=IFS(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ABC",B27)),"Section One",(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DEF",B27))),"Section Two",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("GHI",B27)),"Section Three",@ISNUMBER(LEFT(B27,3)={"'.'!E2:E10"})>0,"text output one",@ISNUMBER(LEFT(B27,3)={"'.'!F2:F5"})>0,"text output two,TRUE,"")`

The portion of code not working:

`@ISNUMBER(LEFT(B27,3)={"'.'!E2:E10"})>0,"text output one",@ISNUMBER(LEFT(B27,3)={"'.'!F2:F5"})>0,"text output two"`

The name of the second sheet in the Workbook is `.`

The arrays I am attempting to use in the above formula:

[Screenshot of the arrays - First array: E2:E10. Second array: F2:F5.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckzfa.png)

I have also tried using just LEFT, as below, but the cell just returns the final `,TRUE,"")` as the output:

`LEFT(B27,3)={"'.'!E2:E10"},"output text one",LEFT(B27,3)={"'.'!F2:F5"},"output text two"`

Comment: `ISNUMBER(MATCH(LEFT(B27,3),'.'!E2:E10,0))` same with the other.

Comment: @ScottCraner saved again, it's amazing how easy it is to over complicate things in hindsight! thanks Scott.